# Send commands to GPS receiver

Tags: java, android

How to send commands to GPS receiver?

I used LocationManager to get location details, but couldn't find how to send NMEA commands (like GPXTE,GPRMB...) to GPS receiver.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the android documentation section [Send Emulator Console Commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console.html#querycontrol) to understand in details on this.

> Geographic location

Set the geographic location reported to the apps running inside an emulator by sending a GPS fix to the emulator.
You can issue the geo command as soon as a virtual device is running. The emulator sets the location you enter by creating a mock location provider. This provider responds to location listeners set by apps, and also supplies the location to the [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). Any app can query the location manager to obtain the current GPS fix for the emulated device by calling `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps")`

> geo Command

The format is **geo < fix|nmea >**

**geo fix longitude latitude satellites [altitude]**

Send a simple GPS fix to the emulator. Specify longitude and latitude in decimal degrees. Use a number from 1 to 12 to specify the number of satellites to use to determine the position, and specify altitude in meters.

**geo nmea sentence**

Send an NMEA 0183 sentence to the emulated device, as if it were sent from an emulated GPS modem. Start sentence with '$GP'. Only '$GPGGA' and '$GPRCM' sentences are currently supported. The following example is a GPGGA (Global Positioning System Fix Data) sentence that gets the time, position, and fix data for a GPS receiver:

```
geo nmea $GPGGA ,hhmmss.ss,llll.ll,a,yyyyy.yy,a,x,xx,x.x,x.x,M,x.x,M,x.x,xxxx
```

For example:

```
geo fix 121.5 25.4 10 

geo nmea $GPRMC,071236,A,3751.65,S,14527.36,E,000.0,073.0,130309,011.3,E*62
```

The geo command can send the GPS location to the emulator. geo fix sends a set of fixed GPS locations represented by longitude, latitude, and height, which can be obtained from the map on some web sites, such as longitude 121.5, latitude 25.4, and height 10 meters. When the Android device is connected to an external GPS device via USB, you can use the geo nmea command to send locations to the external GPS device.

**The National Electrical Manufacturers Association (NEMA)** developed the NMEA 0183 protocol for GPS devices. The format of gps nema command is complicated and composed of 12 fields, but thanks to this complexity, the command provides more accurate positioning than the geo fix command. The format of the gps nema command is as follows:

```
$GPRMC,<1>,<2>,<3>,<4>,<5>,<6>,<7>,<8>,<9>,<10>,<11>,<12>*hh 

$GPRMC,hhmmss.ss,A,IIII.II,a,yyyyy.yy,a,x.x,x.x,ddmmyy,x.x,a*hh

$GPRMC (Recommended minimum specific GPS/Transit data)
```

> Reference

- [Android Application Development for the Intel Platform](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=BVonCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&pg=GBS.PA186.w.10.0.42#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Send Emulator Console Commands](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BVonCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=gps%20receiver%20send%20command%20android&source=bl&ots=_oM2vMaYyf&sig=BwtMSnbC3iA9JorKopwSHvAnEZE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOsPzh0cfYAhVKKo8KHdJADZsQ6AEITTAG#v=onepage&q&f=false)